# EKS GPU worker group using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, gpu, amazon-eks

Using the [terraform EKS module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest), how do you use GPU nodes?

The [EKS docs](https://eksctl.io/usage/gpu-support/) suggest that GPU support is automatic, but some [guides/tutorials](https://deploying.ai/aws-eks-gpu-nvidia/) suggest that the user has to install the nvidia-device-plugin and configure AMIs themselves?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the worker groups to use a specific AMI image, and install the NVIDIA device plugin.

There is an [image_id](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/65777d0a37791dd1200d478e3bacc4c9a75f24c8/workers.tf#L183) property for the `worker_groups` block.

Find the appropriate AMI image [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-optimized-ami.html), selecting the `x86 accelerated` link under the appropriate kubernetes version and AWS region for your cluster. Copy the AMI id, eg for k8s 1.18 in eu-west-2 you need [ami-027a09e5aa5a67e59](https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/parameters/%252Faws%252Fservice%252Feks%252Foptimized-ami%252F1.18%252Famazon-linux-2-gpu%252Frecommended%252Fimage_id/description?region=eu-west-2).

Then plug in your AMI id as `image_id` in your `worker_groups` config eg:

```yaml
module "eks" {
  worker_groups = [
    {
      image_id = "ami-027a09e5aa5a67e59"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, you need to [install the nvidia-device-plugin](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#installing-via-helm-installfrom-the-nvidia-device-plugin-helm-repository), which could be performed within terraform using the [helm provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs):

```yaml
resource "helm_release" "k8s-device-plugin" {
  name  = "k8s-device-plugin"
  repository = "https://nvidia.github.io/k8s-device-plugin"
  chart = "nvidia-device-plugin"
  version = "0.6.0"
  namespace = "kube-system"
}
```

You should now be able to [run GPU pods](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#running-gpu-jobs) by requesting the `nvidia.com/gpu` resource type.

Comment: Note: https://deploying.ai/aws-eks-gpu-nvidia/ has some more info.

Comment: I don't understand how I associate the plugin with the worker group, can you elucidate?